# WordPress Search Form Doesn't Resize on Zoom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs

The link to my site is http://www.tutorialboy.com.
I'm having issues with the search box.
Every time when I zoom in at 150% or higher the search box gets out of position.
I'm using the twenty eleven theme.
I just customized a few things in it.
I just want the search box to stay in place like it does when I don't zoom in.
I'm new to the whole web design thing so please forgive me if I do anything wrong on this site.
Just comment if you need any extra details & I'll work with you to find them.
Just go to my site please & see if you can figure out my problem.
These are the style rules I customized:

```
input#s {
    background: url(images/search.png) no-repeat 5px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 28px;
    text-align: center;
}

#branding #searchform {
    position: absolute;
    top: 169px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: 10px solid #000;
}


#branding #s {
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-property: width, background;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-transition-property: width, background;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    width: 940px;
}

#branding #s:focus {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 940px;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @ElijahMurray, Not IE specific, Google Chrome does the same.

Comment: @Devin Smith; My eyes.... my poor poor eyes! Anyway; Basic issue is that your input has a fixed width; the rest of the site is responsive; You need to make the input responsive as well.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make the form width be 100%, and add box-sizing #branding #searchform, and then add the CSS attribute `box-sizing:border-box;`. This will make sure that it includes padding and margins in the 100%, instead of bleeding.

```
#branding #searchform {
position: absolute;
top: 169px;
right: 0px;
text-align: right;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
color:#ffffff;
border: 10px solid #000;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```